# Cards Stack RecyclerView - Android library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I need the exact equivalent of (or something very close to) this iOS library for Android:
https://github.com/hfrahmann/HFCardCollectionViewLayout

The overall idea is to have something like a cards stack:

[image: Screenplay]

Can you help me?

Comment: check this https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this use **[CardStackview](https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView)**

> One Custom view for show something just like cards with animations.

```
<com.loopeer.cardstack.CardStackView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

CardStackView mStackView = (CardStackView) findViewById(R.id.stackview_main);
```

sample image
[image]